# siunitx nested "per" symbols

Tags: siunitx

I am attempting to type the following using siunitx:

`K/(W/m)`

which is how this quantity is commonly written in my field. I was hoping `\si{\kelvin\per\watt\per\meter}` would do it, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$\si[per-mode=symbol]{\kelvin\per(\watt\per\meter)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could use parentheses in the macro, too. Thanks!