# Multiple levels of "per" in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Suppose I have two units: one is simple, like `\meter`, the other is already a `per`combination of multiple units: `\mega\watt\day\per\kilo\gram`. I now would like to combine these in a fraction. How can I "force" `siunitx` to not move about the different parts of the unit. See MWE below. The last line of the table is what I'm aiming for.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareSIUnit[]\myunit{\mega\watt\day\per\kilo\gram}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  \SI{1}{\meter} \\

  \SI{1}{\myunit} \\

  \SI{1}{\meter\per\myunit}\\

  1 $\frac{\text{m}}{\sfrac{\text{MWd}}{\text{kg}}}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unit's don't work like that: `\metre\per\myunit` gets turned into `\metre\per\mega\watt\day\per\kilo\gram` internally, then reconstructed for the output. All units are at the same 'level' in that sense.

Comment: That can be rearranged: m/(MW d/kg) = kg m/(MW d)

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yes, but that is what I would like to avoid. The separate units are "meaningful": MWd/kg is the amount of energy release per kilogram of raw material. I don't want the "day" or the "kilogram" to move around... And then, I want to combine this "complex unit" with another unit without breaking up the complex unit...

Comment: @JosephWright: okay. Thanks for the feedback. I understand that the behaviour I'm looking for is not compatible with the philosophy of `siunitx`. So for this one, I'll use \num and add the unit myself hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

I just searched the same issue in SI units and luckily found the answer:
refer to: [siunitx nested "per" symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495362/siunitx-nested-per-symbols?rq=1)

So what you could do is simple, that is to add parenthesis to your unit. This suits most nested cases.

```
\SI{1}{\meter\per\ (myunit)}
```

Comment: That just forces the formatting, disabling any chance to reformat